# Slick js мелькают слайды.

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Инициализирую слайдер вот так:

```js
mainSlider.slick({
    autoplay: mainSlider.data("autoplay"),
    autoplaySpeed: Number(mainSlider.data("autoplay-speed")),
    prevArrow: '<div class="main-slider__arrow main-slider__arrow_revers main-slider__arrow_prev"></div>',
    nextArrow: '<div class="main-slider__arrow main-slider__arrow_next"></div>',
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    dotsClass: 'main-slider-dots',
    customPaging: function(slider, i) {
      return '<div class="main-slider-dots__dot"></div>';
    },
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 922,
      settings: {
        arrows: false
      }
    }]
  });
```

При загрузке страницы вижу сначала колонку всех картинок (слайдов), а через секунду это всё собирается в слайдер. 
Как убрать данный эффект?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть в том, что у вас сначала загружаются картинки, а потом это всё по средствам js оборачивается в слайдер. Т.е. от момента загрузки до инициализации слайдера, у вас в любом случае будут картинки.
Вот как один из вариантов - сделать блоку opacity: 0, а по инициализации возвращать opacity: 1

```
.slider { opacity: 0 }

mainSlider.on('init', function(slick){
  mainSlider.css('opacity', 1);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, я сделал что-то похожее. Назначил в css своему классу слайдера visibility: hidden, а классу slick-initialized - visibility: visible;

Comment: да, тоже вариант...